# Need help with particles to understand sentences

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning, particles

first english is not my mothertongue, so if i make mistakes, correction are welcome. i'm reading an adult light novel and have some problem translating and understanding precisely two sentences. First i will give the whole paragraph for context:

> 自分の身体すらも認識することのできない、心地良い浮遊感。*まるでゆりかごに揺られるかのように、ゆっくり**と**、 その意識は傾いては元の位置**へと**戻る*。奇妙な感覚ではあったが、 それは決して不快ではなかった。***すでに記憶にはない、母の胎内というのはこんな感覚なのだろうか、とぼんやりとした思考が生まれて、そして流れていく。***

The first phrase i don't understand is this sentence:

> まるでゆりかごに揺られるかのように、ゆっくりと、 その意識は傾いては元の位置へと戻る

It's not that i don't understand the vocabulary,i understand it very well. It's about the two particles i marked in bold, と and へと, especially へと which giving me trouble in understanding the phrase and translating it precisely in my head.

The second i cannot translate it in my head at all, i don't know if it's because i got troubled with that other phrase but i really cannot understand the phrase. It's the phrase which I put in bold above:

> すでに記憶にはない、母の胎内というのはこんな感覚なのだろうか、とぼんやりとした思考が生まれて、そして流れていく

Why are there two は particles in the phrase? Can someone help me please?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24943/what-is-the-purpose-of-adding-%E3%81%A8 (for ゆっくりと) and https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9343/particle-%E3%81%A8-with-%E3%81%B8-%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%B8%E3%81%A8 (for へと).

Comment: Please 1) avoid asking more than one thing at a time, 2) try to show your translation attempt, and 3) use a specific title.

Comment: Ah i'm sorry naruto, the next time i ask a question i will do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. と after ゆっくり is "the optional と". This is a FAQ.

   - [What does adding と after an adverb do?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42163/5010)
   - [What is the purpose of adding と?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24943/5010)
   - [What role does と play in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36764/5010)
   - [usage of と in this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/49003/5010)
2. と after 元の位置へ is explained in this question.

   - [Particle と with へ; ～へと](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9343/5010)
3. すでに記憶にはない is a relative clause that modifies 母の胎内. "The internal of Mother's uterus, about which I no longer have memory." The first は is は used with negative clauses. 「すでに記憶にはない、母の胎内というのはこんな感覚なのだろうか」 is the content of his 思考.

   - [Why is the topic marker often used in negative statements (ではない, ～とは思わない)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1077/5010)

Comment: Thank you very much naruto, this will help me to understand  the text better, thank you very much again.