# 「ヘト」という意味はなんですか。

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-choice, usage, nuances

I tried looking up へと in the sentence スカイテラスへと続く廊下。but that didn’t yield much results towards my comprehension on the matter.

I know the sentence means something like “The corridor lead to the sky terrace.” But I don’t understand why the use of へと instead of just と.

I already read an answer on a similar question on StackExchange ([link to source here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9343/particle-%E3%81%A8-with-%E3%81%B8-%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%B8%E3%81%A8)) but, although I really appreciate the answers on that question, I still don’t understand it.

Thank you for reading and possibly helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don’t understand why the use of へと instead of just と.

Okay, let's try using "just と" and see what happens

> スカイテラス**と**続く廊下。

I can only parse this as "sky terrace *and* continuing corridor". continuing from and to where? Nobody knows. So, this sentence does not make much sense to me.

However, if we take the original:

> スカイテラス**へと**続く廊下。

Then it's clearly "corridor continuing *to (towards)* the sky terrace", which makes much more sense.

As for why `へと` instead of just `へ`, see the discussion you linked. Personally, it feels like it specifies both direction and the end point, i.e. the corridor continues towards and until the sky terrace, ending there.

A few examples from [weblio](https://ejje.weblio.jp/):

> Public opinion swayed **towards** declaring war on Russia.
>
> その前の対露開戦**へと**国論が傾いた。
>
> we ran head over heels **toward** the shelter
>
> 私達は一目散に避難所**へと**走った
>
> She shopped around from store **to** store.
>
> 店から店**へと**買い物をして回った