# Is 受け繋が usage here correct?

Tags: grammar, meaning, translation, particles

> アレキサンダー、ハンニバル、ローマの将軍達**へと受け繋が**れてきた英雄達の包囲殲滅戦法

This comment was on a video about the battle of mohacs wherein the ottomens used the pincer attack to win . i think the commenter wanted to say that they - the ottomans - got their tactics from the likes of hanabille and so but i am confused by  the へと受け繋がれてきた part/ is it grammatically correct ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is grammatically correct. I'm not sure what part of this sentence confused you, but 受け繋ぐ is a compound verb that is less common but means almost the same thing as [受け継ぐ](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%8F%97%E3%81%91%E7%B6%99%E3%81%90). This へと is an emphatic version of へ (see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9343/5010)).

- **受け繋ぐ**: "to inherit"
- **受け繋がれる**: "to be inherited" (passive)
- **受け繋がれてくる**: "to be inherited (over time)" ([-てくる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/677/5010) added)
- **受け繋がれてきた**: "was inherited (over time)" (past)

> アレキサンダー、ハンニバル、ローマの将軍達へと受け繋がれてきた英雄達の包囲殲滅戦法
> the heroes' tactics of siege and extermination that was inherited down to Alexander, Hannibal, and Roman generals

Comment: here is the thing, shouldn't the later generation inherit from the early generation . "inherited down to' does not make sense because they are the one who pass down  the tactics ..... not

Comment: @user50156 This phrase means that Alexander, Hannibal, and Roman generals all **learned** the tactics from someone earlier, not **taught**, so "inherited **to**" is correct. I don't know who they learned it from, but there should be some ancestor not directly mentioned in this sentence.